# My ply lex recognizes int numbers incorrectly

Tags: python, compiler-errors, lex, ply

My lex needs to identify if the input is a Bin, Hex, Float, Int or ID. It identifies all correctly but if the input is, for example, 2i, it says that it is an Int and doesn't say its an error. Can I have some advice, please?

Here is my code:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# lex.py
#
# Lex
# 
# ------------------------------------------------------------

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "../..")

import ply.lex as lex

#------------------------------RESERVED--------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

reserved = {

    'if' : 'IF',
    'then' : 'THEN',
    'else' : 'ELSE',
    'while' : 'WHILE',
    'true' : 'TRUE',
    'false' : 'FALSE',
    'print' : 'PRINT',
    'input' : 'INPUT',
    'output' : 'OUTPUT',
    'end' : 'END',

    #---------------TYPES----------------
    #---------------------------------------------

    'void' : 'VOID',
    'char' : 'CHAR',
    'unsigned' : 'UNSIGNED',
    'bool' : 'BOOL',}  

#-----------------------TOKENS-------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

tokens = [

   'ID',
   'INT',
   'FLOAT',
   'HEX',
   'BIN',

    #------------------OP-----------------
    #---------------------------------------------
   'PLUS',
   'MINUS',
   'TIMES',
   'DIVIDE',
   'OR',
   'AND',
   'NOT',
   'XOR',

    #------------------DEL--------------
    #---------------------------------------------
   'LPAREN', 'RPAREN',
   'LBRACKET', 'RBRACKET',
   'LBRACE', 'RBRACE',
   'COMMA', 'PERIOD', 'SEMI', 'COLON',
   'COMMENT',

    #----------------ASSIGN------------------
    #---------------------------------------------
   'EQUALS'

] + list(reserved.values())

#-----------------------------DEFINITIONS-------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #------------------OP-----------------
    #---------------------------------------------
t_PLUS         = r'\+'
t_MINUS        = r'-'
t_TIMES        = r'\*'
t_DIVIDE       = r'/'
t_OR               = r'\|'
t_AND              = r'&'
t_NOT              = r'~'
t_XOR              = r'\^'

    #----------------DEL----------------
    #---------------------------------------------
t_LPAREN           = r'\('
t_RPAREN           = r'\)'
t_LBRACKET         = r'\['
t_RBRACKET         = r'\]'
t_LBRACE           = r'\{'
t_RBRACE           = r'\}'
t_COMMA            = r','
t_PERIOD           = r'\.'
t_SEMI             = r';'
t_COLON            = r':'

    #----------------ASSIGN------------------
    #---------------------------------------------
t_EQUALS           = r'='


reserved_map = { }
for r in reserved:
    reserved_map[r.lower()] = r


    #-------------BIN-----------
    #---------------------------------------------

def t_BIN(t):
    r'0b\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value,2)
    return t

    #-----------HEX---------
    #---------------------------------------------
def t_HEX(t):
    r'0x([abcdef]|\d)+'
    t.value = int(t.value,16)
    return t

    #-----------FLOAT------------
    #---------------------------------------------
def t_FLOAT(t):
    r'\d+\.\d+'
    t.value = float(t.value)
    return t

    #-----------INT--------------
    #---------------------------------------------
def t_INT(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)    
    return t

    #-------------ID----------------
    #---------------------------------------------
def t_ID(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'
    t.type = reserved.get(t.value,'ID')    # Check for reserved words
    return t

    #-----------LINES-----------
    #---------------------------------------------
def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)

    #-------------COMMENT-----------
    #---------------------------------------------
def t_COMMENT(t):
    r'\#.*'
    pass

    #---------IGNORE--------
    #---------------------------------------------
t_ignore  = ' \t'

    #--------------ERROR--------------
    #---------------------------------------------
def t_error(t):
    print("Wrong Character: '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

# Lexer
lexer = lex.lex()


#lex.lex(debug=0)

while True:
    s = input('input > ')
    lexer.input(s)
    tok = lexer.token()
    if not tok:
        break
    print(tok)
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be a closing curly brace just before `tokens`?

Comment: As for the question, if you request the next token it'll be an `ID` with the value `"i"`. I think it's normal behavior, this combination can be recognized as a syntax error on parsing stage (unless your lexer can backtrack).

Comment: oops, yes!, there is a brace, i just edited it :)

Comment: hmm interesting ... I just tried "0b1hello" as an input and it recognizes it as a BIN. I will try my lex with my parser now, and maybe it will tell me if its an error or not! :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it recognizes just the `0b1` part as `BIN`, try fetching the next token. As I said, a combination of `BIN` followed by `ID` may be grammatically correct or not, it's something a parser should decide.

Comment: You were totally right! Much obliged!!!